# Cannot install Windows 8 because it can't create a new partition

Tags: windows-8

After my operating system Windows 8 crashed, I tried to format my hard-disk but Windows 8 shows error:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the setup files.

I tried to solve it as follows:

- Repair computer
- go to advanced tools
- start command line
- start `DISKPART`
- type `LIST DISK` and identify my disk number as disk 0
- type `SELECT DISK 0`
- type `CLEAN`
- `CLEAN PARTITION PRIMARY`
- `ACTIVE`
- `FORMAT FS = NTFS QUICK`
- `ASSIGN`
- `EXIT` (twice)

I've combined my disk to a single one, there are no other disk partitions when I tried the above.

Any Idea? Is my hard-disk is damaged or is this a software problem?
I have recovered all data from the hard disk to another external hard disk with a Fedora 15 Live CD.

Comment: It sounds like you can't convince Windows to purge current partitions. i had trouble convincing Windows to delete the special **System Reserved** partition. i can't remember how i solved it; enough selecting, and deleting, and purging, and removing. But i suggest the brute force approach. Download Western Digital's hard-drive tools, and tell it to **Write all zeros to the drive**. That will get rid of every partition. That way Windows can't refuse.

Comment: While you have the WD tools you might as well use it to check the hard drive and make sure a failing HD is't the root of the cause, also, you might want to run memtest86+ (1 pass), bad RAM can cause all sorts of strange issues as well..

Comment: Can you use GParted live cd and post a screenshot here?

Comment: I also had the same issue @Bishnu . I couldn't get any help from internet. Every internet thread says to check for any other extra hdd or any kind of sd card is plugged or not. Very lately I found that the installation media (8gb Transcend) has a SecureDrive(CDFS file system) this was the main reason I couldn't able to install the os. So I just did the installation through another pendrive which doesn't have any extra partition. Eveything went successfully. Uffffffff.. It took me a whole day to find out this. I hope this might help you

Comment: @Bishnu Bhattarai, similar situation was resolved after updating/flashing the BIOS

Answer (score 4):

If you are installing from a USB device and you are getting this error, then try this. Go to repair/cmd and copy all the files from USB to the drive where you wish to install to. If D: is USB, E: is your Windows partition, then type in these commands.

```
D:
xcopy /E /H *.* E:\
```

Then set your Windows partition as active with diskpart:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
```

Where X is your HDD or SSD where you want to install Windows.

```
list partition
select partition X
active
exit
```

Now unplug the USB, close cmd window and reboot the PC. Now the installer will start from your HDD and you can install to the same location. You can delete the installation files when you're done (compare with USB contents).

Comment: I had the same error as a question author and this solution worked great as an alternative to `diskpart clean`. `diskpart clean` deletes all partitions - it's not good if you don't want to lose your data. I did it once by mistake and I had to recover my partition with `testdisk` tool. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: This guy is brilliant,  this solution worked for me and saved me . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

another reason for this error could be because of attaching multiple usbs/SD card. Detach all USBs, SD card and External HDD other than the Windows live USB. It should work.

Comment: I can confirm this. http://serverfault.com/questions/812062/unable-to-install-windows-server

Answer (score 0):

After you rewrite the partition table, reboot the computer. This has solved the issue for me several times. It looks to me like Windows isn't able to detect when the table changes until then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a USB 2.0 flash disk instead of a USB 3.0 disk regardless whether the target system has USB 3.0 ports or not. (Assuming of course that the installation is being done with a USB flash disk)